# Spring Security basic auth for REST Api single login needed?

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am using Spring Security basic auth for my REST API.

Initially I get **unauthorized** HTTP response status for unauthenticated secured routes.

If I provide the right credentials, I get a **Ok** HTTP response status, but after **a single successful login**, I can access all the secured routes without providing user credentials.

**Here are my questions:**

1. Is it the correct behaviour for basic authentication?
2. Why it happens?

My security config:

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userService);
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authenticationProvider;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        //J-
        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/save")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/h2-console/**")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic();
        //J+

        //adding support for h2 console, otherwise crashes
        http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }
}
```

and here is the **UserDetailsService's** **loadByUsername()** method:

```
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) {
    User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);

    if (user == null) {
        throw new UserNotFoundException(username);
    } else if (UserStatus.Deactivated.equals(user.getStatus())) {
        throw new UserDeactivatedException(username);
    }

    return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), Collections.singleton(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("USER")));
}
```

Comment: Are you sending jsessionid? Moreover, as per rest coventions api should be stateless, so you should send auth header everytime

Comment: I can see jsessionid in the cookies in postman

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-session refer this. Also for restful api use stateless session policy

Comment: it solved my problem. Post it please as an answer so that I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-session

Refer mentioned link. For Restful API’s use stateless session policy